# Adding Adobe files to a wordpress site

Tags: uploads, filesystem

I need to give members access to Adobe files, Illustrator, InDesign, and Photoshop on my website. Is there a plugin or someway I can put those on my site for people to access and download?

Answer (score 3):

Allowing file types outside of WP's defaults exposes your site to some security risks, and some hosts don't allow certain filetypes. If your host allows these filetypes, you can use the following function in a plugin or a child theme:

```
function wpse_file_uploads($mime_types){
    // photoshop
    $mime_types['psd'] = 'image/vnd.adobe.photoshop';
    // illustrator
    $mime_types['ai'] = 'application/postscript';
    // indesign
    $mime_types['indd'] = 'application/x-indesign';
    return $mime_types;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'wpse_file_uploads', 1, 1);
```

Probably best to put this in a custom plugin because if you or another user switch themes later, you won't want to lose this functionality.